# Renormalizability of massless Gross-Neveu theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, renormalization, dimensional-analysis, quantum-chromodynamics

We have the following Lagrangian density:

$$ \mathcal{L} =  \bar{\psi}_i i \gamma^\mu \partial_\mu \psi_i
+ \frac{g^2}{2} \left( \bar{\psi}_i \psi_i \right)^2 $$

which corresponds to the two-dimensional massless [Gross-Neveu theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gross%E2%80%93Neveu_model).

We also consider the following gamma matricies:

$$ \gamma^0 = \sigma^2 = \left( \begin{array}{cc}
    0 & -i \\
    i & 0
\end{array} \right) , \hspace{0,3cm} \gamma^1 = i \sigma^1 = \left( \begin{array}{cc}
0 & i \\
i & 0
\end{array} \right) , \hspace{0,3cm} \gamma^5 = \sigma^3 = \left(  \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & -1
\end{array} \right) $$

where $\sigma^i$ are the Pauli matricies. After showing that it is invariant over the transformation $\psi_i \rightarrow \gamma_5 \psi_i$, how can we prove that this theory is renormalizable?

Comment: Hint: Start by showing that $g$ is dimensionless.

Comment: @Qmechanic How do we do that? Could you provide an answer

Comment: Look at the kinetic term first. What is the dimension of ψ? Its square? Its fourth power? Surely you've covered power counting in your course.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Nevermind,  I arrived at $[g]=0$, but that condition although is suficient it is not enough to prove renormalizability. What do I do next?

Comment: Explain. Sufficient normally means enough…

Comment: Just because $[g]=0$ that is a statement that allows for renormalizability but doesn't guarantee it right? Don't we need to see the amplitudes of Feynman diagrams, perhaps in lowest orders, to effectively check that there aren't any divergences?

Comment: @CosmasZachos My bad, it is a necessary condition although not enough, that's what I meant. Is my statement correct?

Comment: No, I think it is enough; review your power-counting drill. The full renormalization of this model is in many reviews and books.